# AutoHotkey send all modifiers expect one

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to map (Right windows key) + (i) to (up) + (modifiers). this is what i have so far.

```
RWin & i::send {Blind}{Up}
```

The problem with this is it sends Up with the right windows key and causes mayhem!

Is there a way to send all modifiers + up EXCEPT the right windows key modifier?

Comment: Please look up the `{Blind}` keyword at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm . If you omit it, the windows button will not be sent. Is this your problem?

Comment: yes it will only run the up key, but i need it to run up + any other key. right now its running up + any other key like shift + window key. i want to remove the window key from the equation.

Comment: sorry I don't get you. You want to send "all modifiers"? like `RWin & i::sendInput ^+!{up}`? This would **not** send the windows key together with `up`, only ctrl shift alt .. we have a major misunderstanding

Comment: My understanding is that he would like to allow any additional modifiers that he is pushing. ie. He is pressing Ctrl + RWin + i, then it will send Ctrl + Up.

Comment: yes Elliot has it, thats the idea. is this possible?

Comment: ok. add an `*` asterisk, so it*s `*RWin & *i` or sth. that will solve it. no time for answer sry. bb

Comment: How about something like `RWin & i::Send {Blind}{RWin Up}{Up}`?

Comment: Hmm adding a *Rwin gives me a compile error "invalid hotkey". adding RWin & i::Send {Blind}{RWin Up}{Up} prevents the (Rwin Up) to fire but for some reason fires the (RWin) and causes the start menu to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your hotkey to work, *even if other modifiers like ctrl, alt, shift are being held down*, You need to use the `*` (wildcard) modifier:

> [*] Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down

My initially proposed solution `*RWin & *i` does not work because the wildcard modifier only works with 'common' hotkeys like `*^h::msgbox`. Actually, `RWin & i` is not the best way to define this action: You could make use of the `>` modifier:

> [>] Use the right key of the pair.

Your hotkey will look like this:

```
*>#i::send {up}
```

`#` is the Windows key, just like `^` is Ctrl and so on.

---

Note:

> When {Blind} is the first item in the string, the program avoids releasing Alt/Control/Shift/Win if they started out in the down position.

But you want RWin **not** to be sent (this is standard), so you should avoid the `{blind}` keyword which triggers the exact opposite of what you seem to aim for.

source of information: [https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Intro)

Comment: Im having a hard time implementing this, *>#i:send {Up} does not work out of the box.

Comment: sorry, "spelling error" - has to be `*>#i::send {up}`, of course. one `:` too little.. otherwise ahk does not see it as an hotkey but a label and therefore does not trigger any action. I also corrected it above. Does it work now?

Comment: amazing!! yes it works well. i also added a RWin::return to prevent the start menu from opening.